# How to sell product with discount per box in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is there a way to sell “a box” of some product using different prices?
I guess it would be something like this http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-the-unit-price/, but this option doesnt appear in the Community Edition.

For example: 1 box = 6 items = 10% off

I tried to use tier prices, but the discount for the 7th unit cant be the same, it should be the regular price.

I also tried to use configurable product, but I can’t have a good inventory control, as it will be different products (one for box, and other for single) - like they did here.

An hypothetical situation would be..

A bottle of wine for USD 10,00.

2 bottles for USD 20,00

6 bottles (a box) for USD 55

7 bottles (a box + 1 alone): USD 65  (55+10)

Any ideas to make it possible?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

i am sure that you will achieve this scenario with help of bundle product

you can check detail with [Document LINK](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product)

And also you can apply discount for bundle product. when you are creating product from admin

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: Thanks for replying @liyakat. The problem of using bundled products is that I cant show the box option for the product like this, associating with the main product...

Comment: i can suggest you to make attribute for same and you can manage with box option to show and assign only in bundle product

Comment: We've realized that we don't have this option in Magento. We've saw the possibility of create a module that takes some attributes of the product (like qty/price per box) and applies a discount at the cart. But we ended to convince our client that 1 box with 6 bottles is a different product than 1 bottle alone, so we'll use configurable product (like www.maset.com does) with individual inventory. Thank you for replying anyway.

Comment: welcome @RicardoMartins,good to see you after long time, that will also increase my knowledge to.. thanks once again.

Comment: if my link as little helpful to find way, so i could suggest you to vote up so some one can little utilize it.